# cambiar flechas next y prev en la libreria swiper

Tags: reactjs, icons, slide, styled-components, swiper

buen día, estoy trabajando con react y la librería swiper y styled-components para realizar un slide. El tema es que necesito cambiar las flechas que trae por defecto por unas mas gruesas.
Estoy intentando cargar alguna tipografía de iconos como icomoon para luego darle como `font-family` esa tipografía y con `content:` seleccionar el icono que tengo que utilizar pero no estoy teniendo éxito...

lo que probé es insertar en el `<head>` los estilos de icomoon (linea:90)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/fonts-archive/icomoon/style.css"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

darle al `:after` la configuración

```
.swiper-button-next,
  .swiper-button-prev {
    color: #fff;
    &::after {
      font-size: 20px; 
      font-family: "icomoon";
      content: "\e900"
    }
  }
```

y el elemento inspeccionado lo toma (aunque sin la barra invertida)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no se carga el icono

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probé también configurar la fuente en los estilos globales

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'swiper-custom';
    src: url('/fonts-archive/icomoon/fonts/icommon.woff') format('woff');    //agregar fuente icommon
        font-weight: normal;  
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

y darle a `:after` el `font-family: "swiper-custom"`
pero tampoco funciono

cuando lo he hecho con html y css funcionaba bien hacer esto pero no logro adaptarlo a react y styled-components parece. Desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Si la fuente la cargas bajo el nombre `swiper-custom`, luego tienes que llamarla con ese mismo nombre, entonces debes cambiar `font-family: "icomoon";` por `font-family: "swiper-custom";`

Comment: eso mismo lo intente y no resulto (como aclare abajo)
Igual gracias por tu comentario :) sigo buscando como resolverlo aun...